Connecting from DBeaver using Astra JDBC driver returns "Invalid Credentials"
I need to connect to Astra using DBeaver. I'm following guide https://awesome-astra.github.io/docs/pages/data/explore/dbeaver/#astra-community-jdbc-drivers (exactly "Astra Community JDBC Drivers" section as Simba driver does not support some cqlsh features like describe tables and display some specific tables incorrectly).
I have astra bundle (zip file) and clientId, secret and token
The problem is that I cannot connect any way:

using "token" as username and token value as the password - I'm getting error Error Code=401, (HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) Invalid Credentials Check your token: null
using "clientId" as username and "secret" as the passwprd - error is Error Code=401, (HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) Invalid Credentials Check your token: {"errors":[{"ID":340002,"message":"no bearer token in request"}]}

Connection URL is like this:
jdbc:astra://some-long-aws-url.com:29080/my_keyspace;AuthMech=2;TunableConsistency=6;SecureConnectionBundlePath=/Users/user/astra/astra-bundle.zip

Also I've tried to use AuthMech as 1 / 2 / 3, do not set URL(as it exists in bundle) like jdbc:astra://;AuthMech=... but nothing helps.
It's not network issue as I can connect using commandline cqlsh-astra package as well as using Simba drivers.

Invalid Credentials Check your token... Are you sure about your credentials?

Are you using a free Astra DB and has it gone into hibernation? Sometimes you get incorrect credential messages from libraries because of that.

@Nifriz - yes, creds are 100% ok (using them to connect from command line)

@philnash - no, it's corporate version on cloud and it's always on.

Oh, I think you might have the connection URL slightly wrong. You have it as the full URL, but the docs say that it should be jdbc:astra://${db}/${keyspace}?region=${region}. So instead of the full URL, try using the database ID (the first part of the URL, before the region, also available on your Astra DB page, under the database name).

Yes, I've tried different variations of it like jdbc:astra://my_db_name/my_keyspace_name - the same error. Also it's strange that when I remove bundle path from connection URL - error is the same. So maybe it cannot read host at all and trying to connect to localhost...

Thanks for posting on Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

It looks like you have configured the wrong JDBC URL, probably because you tried using the Astra JDBC driver and run into issues then you tried using the Simba driver which uses a completely different JDBC URL.
I managed to connect to my Astra DB instance using the Astra JDBC driver by following the instructions on the Awesome Astra document you linked in your post.
Please try to configure a new DB connection but this time using the JDBC URL with the form:
jdbc:astra://db_name/keyspace_name

To use mine as an example, my database is named community and I have a keyspace named stackoverflow so my JDBC URL is:
jdbc:astra://community/stackoverflow


As a side note, I was able to replicate the issue you had by deleting the first character in my token to get the errors:
Unexpected driver error occurred while connecting to the database
  Error in HTTP Request: Error Code=401, (HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) Invalid Credentials Check your token: {"errors":[{"ID":340002,"message":"no bearer token in request"}]}
  Error in HTTP Request: Error Code=401, (HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) Invalid Credentials Check your token: {"errors":[{"ID":340002,"message":"no bearer token in request"}]}
    Error Code=401, (HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) Invalid Credentials Check your token: {"errors":[{"ID":340002,"message":"no bearer token in request"}]}

Verify that you have entered your token correctly. It should be the of the form AstraCS:AbC...XYz:123...edf0. Cheers!

I've left a comment to my question that I've tried specifying db and keyspace (without URL) but still cannot connect. Also I don't see bundle path in your connection details. Regarding your side note - when I'm using token (yes, starting like "AstraCS:aBC...") - error text is "Check your token: null" that differs a bit from "no bearer token in request" in your example. Thanks for suggestion!

You don't specify the bundle path in the JDBC URL when using the Astra JDBC driver since the JAR is uploaded and associated with the driver in the Driver Manager. Cheers!

Also, can you confirm that you are specifically using the Astra JDBC driver? The instructions are slightly different if you are using another driver.

Yes, I'm using astra-jdbc-driver-5.1.jar as custom driver. But I'm a bit confused: if I don't put bundle path to jdbc url field - where the bundle should be specified? I believe it must be mandatory (as contains hostname, certificates, etc). And the astra-jdbc-driver-5.1.jar does not contain any connection details. Or am I missing something?

Like I said, each driver has different instructions for using them so you need to follow the instructions exactly as documented or you will run into issues. The Astra JDBC driver automatically retrieves the secure bundle in the background which is why we don't tell you to add it when we wrote the instructions. Cheers!

Yes, I try to strictly follow the instructions, but it didn't work. Maybe I'm missing something... So do you mean I need to specify only db name, keyspace and token and do not use bundle at all ? As it's strange for me: as even Datastax Studio (kinda recommended application but pretty slow and with outdated UI/UX) requires token AND bundle.

DataStax Studio does NOT use the Astra JDBC driver. It uses the Cassandra Java driver which is a native CQL driver, not JDBC. You cannot assume that all drivers are the same. We have created the Astra JDBC driver as the next generation driver that no longer requires the secure bundle to make it so much easier for users to connect to Astra. Cheers!
